# Get value from search in Dict

Tags: python

```
"data": {
    "0": {
      "name": "test",
      "tag": "123"
    },
    "1": {
      "name": "test123",
      "tag": "456"
```

lets say having this example data above and i wanted to get the tag value of 456 but need to make sure the "name" has test123 value compared in a search. how should i loop this dict?

```
def test():
    response = requests.get(data_above)
    data_dict = json.loads(response.text)

    # need to loop here to get the tag value of 456 and assigned it in variable but is from searching to make sure i have "name" test123 is found. is more towards dynamic
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Exactly what part are you struggling with? How the question is written right now, it's hard for us to know if you're struggling with flow-control or looping-logic. Please show us that you've actually _tried_ to solve the problem before asking us.

Comment: Can you please fix the above code block? It should be runnable. What does the data structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

The data structure in the original question is incomplete. Making an assumption about how it really looks then this would work:

```
mydict = [{"data": {
    "0": {
        "name": "test",
        "tag": "123"
    },
    "1": {
        "name": "test123",
        "tag": "456"}
    }
}]
for v in mydict[0]['data'].values():
    if v['name'] == 'test123':
        print(v['tag'])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values' getting this error

Comment: @user1897151 Your data_dict is almost certainly a list. I'll adjust my code on that assumption

Answer (score 0):

You can use [“the item name”] for calling it
like:

```
dict = {“data” : {
     “0” : {
        “name” : “test”,
        “tag” : “123”
     },
     “1” : {
        “name” : “test123”,
        “tag” : “456”
     }
}

#searching
for val in mydict:
    #scan for each level
    if val == “test”:
         print(“i found”)
    else:
         for i in mydict[val]:
               if i == “test”:
                     print(“i found”)
               else:
                     for item in mydict[val][i]:
                           res = mydict[val][i][item]
                           if res == “test”:
                                  print(“I found it in final step!”)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searched_name = "test123"
for v in myDict["data"]:
        if v["name"] == searched_name:
             tag = v["tag"]

expected outcome:
tag variable will hold value of 456 now
```

this is working for me. i might be posting my question wrongly but thanks to anyone who tried to helped me. Certainly some gave me idea in how to loop it